# How to create a html button with a hyperlink using xslt

Tags: html, xslt

Using the xslt construction (xml to html)

```html
<a href="{@href}"><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></a>
```

I get a link and the link of the tekst f.e.

```html
<a href="https://any.website.nl/datafeeds/with/a/considerable/long/tekst/string/">https://any.website.nl/datafeeds/with/a/considerable/long/tekst/string/</a>
```

In stead of the text of the link i want a button with the link. The output should be:

```html
<a href="https://any.website.nl/datafeeds/with/a/considerable/long/tekst/string/"><button>button text</button></a>
```

How do i arrange this / how do i change the code snippet:

```html
<a href="{@href}"><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></a>
```

?

Comment: You can just do `<a href="{@href}"><button>button text</button></a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `button` tag over your xsl tag,

```
From : <a href="{@href}"><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></a>

To : <a href="{@href}"><button><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></button></a>
```

Source : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_value_of.asp